# Android4.x (chrome)でpreventDefaultとフリックを共存させるにはどうしたらいいのですか？

Tags: javascript, android

Android4.x(chrome) でフリック実装しようとするとtouchstartかtouchmove内にpreventDefault()で機能を止めなくてはいけないのですが、
フリックする箇所がclickやscrollが利いているところなので、それを入れると今度は「クリックできない」「スクロールできない」と機能が失われます。。

[image: ここのリスト型コンテンツの上でフリックしたいのだが、それを実装するにはtuchstart時にpreventDefaultでclickをなしにしないといけない。もしくはtouchmove時(scrollできなくなる)全てが共存する方法がしりたい]

ソースコードはこちらです。。
[Github: 231行目です](https://github.com/kenjimorita/-study_javascript/blob/784e0a8fe703a6cd6ce7342a027ad8d0a2918ca3/newsto2/src/js/flick.js)

フリックと